# push notification using node.js in ios app while develepment

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notification from my app ,I have configured everything.After configuration i got cert.pem and key.pem. I have followed this https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs link . I am able to connect with apple server but not able to send the notification .can anyone help me what can be the issue as i have tried alot but did not get an appropriate solution for my problem. I am using the following code for communicating the apple server 
Thanks in advance.

```
var http = require('http');
var apn = require('apn');
var url = require('url');

var myPhone = "f0e56d999e14ab0504b403efd39b90deb49306045b4ed698e33602abaa862111";
var myDevice = new apn.Device(myPhone);
var note = new apn.Notification();
note.badge = 1;
note.sound = "r.mp3";
note.alert = { "body" : "Your turn!", "action-loc-key" : "Play" , "launch-image" : ""};
note.payload = {'messageFrom': 'Holly'};

note.device = myDevice;

var callback = function(errorNum, notification){
    console.log('Error is: %s', errorNum);
    console.log("Note " + notification);
}
var options = {
    gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', // this URL is different for Apple's Production Servers and changes when you go to production
    errorCallback: callback,
    cert: __dirname+'/_certs/cert.pem',                 
    key:  __dirname+'/_certs/key.pem',                 
    passphrase: null,                 
    port: 2195,                       
    enhanced: true,                   
    cacheLength: 100                  
}
var apnsConnection = new apn.Connection(options);
apnsConnection.sendNotification(note);
```

Comment: Too little information. What lib do you use for apn? What responses or errors from apple servers?

Comment: i am using apn for communicating with apple server and did get any response .. when i am trying to telnet apple server with my cert.pem and key.pem that gives a proper response

Comment: Which code? Also may you provide some logs? Are you sure you are using  sandbox environment for apple gateways (also certificates for sandbox) ?

Comment: ya i have tried to telnet using sandbox and that return me response like  "SSL handshake has read 3687 bytes and written 2053 bytes"

Comment: Usually problem is in certificates. You can try firstly with EasyAPN desktop tool (available in AppStore) make push with your certs

Comment: if problem is with certificates how can i telnet apple server with the same certificate ??? i really do not understand what is going wrong ??